# NPM not available when running installation script

Tags: npm

I have an interesting issue, I have a setup or rails project and the deployment/upgrades works absolutely fine when running as a dedicated user (deploy) who is used to setup everything.

I am using codeDeploy to manage the deployments and it uses root user to do the deployment on AWS, but during the deployment it fails on running the same script because it's not able to find npm command

```
cd client && npm run build:client
sh: 1: npm: not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (127): [cd client && npm run build:client...]
```

If i run it manually to check that i also get nothing

```
root@ip-172-31-4-141:/home/ubuntu# su deploy -c "which npm"
root@ip-172-31-4-141:/home/ubuntu#
```

NPM is available via the deploy user but I am struggling to understand why it's not available via the root user

```
deploy@ip-172-31-4-141:/home/ubuntu$ which npm
/home/deploy/.nvm/versions/node/v7.8.0/bin/npm
```

Any help to get this resolved would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: It's installed locally to the `deploy` user. It's in `/home/deploy` so that only that user can run it. Whilst I'd argue that npm shouldn't be running as root the solution would be to install it for the root user too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that AWS CodeDeploy when starts deployment loads only a minimum env; to load all the env variables I have exported the env and then in the deploy phase source that file, which resolves my issue